# Move div left and right on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I have a box that moves right on resize until it disappears at half screen width.

```
    function move() {
        var x = screen.width - window.innerWidth;
        document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft = (x * 2) + "px";
    }
    window.onresize = move;
```

I want that box to gradually move back left at the same pace as it moved right, when it hits the edge of the window.

```
    function move() {
        var x = screen.width - window.innerWidth;
          do {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft = (x * 2) + "px";
        } while (window.innerWidth > "850px");
          do {
        document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft -= (x * 2) + "px";
        } while (window.innerWidth > "850px");
        }
    window.onresize = move;
```

The above code acts as if the second statement is inexistant

Answer (score 0):

Assuming #logo has width = 100px;
You can do this, when the #logo hits the edge of the screen, it will remain there.

```
function move() {
    var pos = 0;
        x = screen.width - window.innerWidth,
        winWidth = (window.innerWidth/2)-50;
        if (x < winWidth) {
            pos = x*2;
        }
        else {
            blockPos = (winWidth - x);
            pos = parseInt(document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft) +blockPos;
        }
        if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
        document.getElementById("logo").style.marginLeft = pos+"px";
    }
window.onresize = move;
```

Comment: did you try it out ? On my end it's only making the logo hit the right edge faster @syahrul

Comment: I did, when the div reached the right side of the screen, it goes back to the left

Comment: Sry man but it's not going at the same pace... it takes it 100px to go back left whereas to get to the right it takes 800px